# Can models be foreign key referenced across different namespaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, namespaces, foreign-keys

I'm trying to work out how to implement namespaces into my app for organisational purposes. However, I'm running into problems trying to establish foreign key references between models in different namespaces, and I haven't been able to find sufficiently detailed guidance online as to how to properly achieve it.

For example, I have a User model without a namespace with a has_many relationship to a model Game. I now also want to give it a has_many relationship to another model Player, which I want to place in a namespace GameFiles.

I used a scaffold to generate the GameFiles namespace and player model as follows:

```
rails g model game_files/player user:references
```

However, the problem is I can't find out what syntax I should use in the User model to specify the `has_many :players` relationship.

If possible, how could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `has_many :players` explicitly like `has_many :players, class_name: GameFiles::Player`?

Comment: Ah thank you so much! That did the trick 